# Can you inject dependencies into an existing angular app?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Lets say I have an app, which I don't know it's reference name or where it's defined.

Let's say I have another module which I've created, (nav module) I want to inject this nav module inside the existing angular app so that it can function as normal.

```
<html ng-app="appA">
  <body>
    <!-- navController exists inside another app -->
    <nav id="testElement" controller="navController"></nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('testElement');
    if (!angular.element(nav).length) return;
    var appElement = angular.element('[ng-app]');
    console.log('appname', appElement.attr('ng-app'));
    var appToInject;
    if (!appElement.length) {
        // Manually run the new app from within js without a ng-app attrib
        appToInject = angular.module('CustomModuleForNavigation', []);
        angular.bootstrap(nav, ['CustomModuleForNavigation']);
    } else {
        appToInject = angular.module(appElement.attr('ng-app'),     []);
    }
    if (angular.isUndefined(appToInject)) return;
    console.log('winning?', appToInject)

    appToInject.controller('navController', function($scope) {
        console.log('extending app in new ctrl!', $scope);
    });

});
```

Comment: do you mean in the sense of putting a widget on someone else's site by you simply adding a script tag? Not 100% clear what objective is here

Comment: Well in a sense yes, I need to extend an existing app, by adding a script to a page, I've added an example.

Comment: The answer would be yes. And you're not giving enough information, because the answer heavily depends on the fact if it is your own app or you are hacking into somebody else's app. Anyway, it is terrible design solution, unless it is the absolute necessity (third-party browser addon for particular site or like that).

Comment: @estus, it's for our client, rather than modify the current 20+ angular apps to work with this new menu module we've created, i wanted to dynamically inject this module into every app so that it functions globally. I figured this out regardless, it's not a terrible design solution, you're extending the apps dependencies, there's nothing wrong with that, I just didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

When there is an existing app module definition, but you want to add additional dependencies to the app module it can be done this way.

```
var existingModule = angular.module('appModuleName');
existingModule.requires.push('additionaldependency');
```

The appModuleName can be found by ng-app attribute of the index.
Make sure this script runs right after the existing module definition script.
Also, scripts required for 'additionaldependency' to be loaded before this script is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out by injecting the dependency into an existing app, or manually running my own up with angular bootstrap.

```
var appElement = $('[ng-app]').first();
function angularJsModuleMerger(elementToBindScope, dependencies) {
    var scopeElement = document.getElementById(elementToBindScope);
    // Dependencies should contain our mobile scopeElement app only, the mobile app should contain it's dependencies.
    if (!angular.element(scopeElement).length) return;
    // If There is an existing angular app, inject our app into it, else, create a new app with our dependencies.
    var hasAngularApp = appElement.length;
    var appToInject;
    if (!hasAngularApp) {
        appToInject = angular.module('appForModularInjection', dependencies);
        // Manually run this app, so that we're not interrupting the current app.
    } else {
        // There is an existing app, so let's get it by it's name
        appToInject = angular.module(appElement.attr('ng-app'));
        // Inject our dependencies to the existing app, IF they don't alreay have these dependencies. 
        // Dependencies must also be loaded previously.
        var currentDependencies = appToInject.requires;
        var newDependencies = currentDependencies.concat(dependencies);
        appToInject.requires = newDependencies;
        appToInject.run(function($rootScope, $compile) {
            $compile(angular.element(scopeElement).contents())($rootScope);
        });
    }
    // If we still don't have an app, well, voodoo.
    if (angular.isUndefined(appToInject)) return;
    // console.log('ok');
    // We must run the app after all the declarations above for both existing and non existing apps.
    if (!hasAngularApp) angular.bootstrap(scopeElement, ['appForModularInjection']);
}
```

This will inject it self to an existing app, manually define an app and bind it all correctly to the element in question.

Scope/hierarchy is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, it is usually done as you've shown here. For the apps which module names you don't know (e.g. bootstrapped with angular.bootstrap) you can hook to angular.module('ng').requires.